# Need explanation on a binomial theorem related problem for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}k$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So I ran into this summation $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}k$$

So I have no idea what to do so I looked at what my professor this.  He said

> If we differentiate this $(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^k$ we have $n(1+x)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}kx^{k-1}$.  Plugging in $x=1$ gives $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}k = n2^{n-1}$.

First of all where did he come up with $(1+x)^n$ and why did he differentiate it?  And then why did he plug in $x = 1$?  I am confused.

Comment: The first equation is just *defining* what the summation coefficient on the right hand side means.   Everything else is presumably done to find a more explicit/"useful" relation for the defined coefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question look at the series expansion of $(1+x)^n$.
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k = 1 + nx + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2...+x^n$$
What happens when you differentiate both sides with respect to x. You get 
$$n(1+x)^{n-1}=n+2\times\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x...+nx^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}kx^{k-1}$$
Now multiply both sides by $x$.
$$nx(1+x)^{n-1}=nx+2\times\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2...+nx^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}kx^{k}$$
Now the right hand sides looks like something you need put $x=1$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}k = n\times2^{n-1}$$

Comment: Hey man sorry I inputed the problem wrong.  There was no $2^k$ there was only k.  But your logic is right! I think I get it now!

Comment: This is a common technique used in summation of many series.

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer**: this is an answer to the original question, that was about $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}k2^k$.

---

Assume to have $n$ white balls and to want to perform the following task:

- Pick some of the balls ($k\geq 1$) and paint them yellow
- Pick some of the yellow balls and paint them red
- Pick a yellow or red ball and [paint it black](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4irXQhgMqg).

It is pretty clear you may select the balls to be painted yellow in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways, a subset of the yellow balls in $2^k$ ways and the ball to be painted black in $k$ ways. Thus the number of ways for performing the above task is exactly $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}k 2^k$ (the contribution given by $k=0$ is irrelevant). On the other hand, the above task can be performed in the following, more efficient way:

- Pick some ball, paint it black and decide if has a yellow or red core ($n$ ways for choosing the ball, $2$ ways for choosing the color of its core)
- For each one of the remaining balls, decide if it stays white, becomes yellow or first yellow then red. $n-1$ balls, $3$ possible choices for each ball.

Conclusion:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}k 2^k = 2n\cdot 3^{n-1}.$$

---

Now the *generating functions* way. We have:
$$ (1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k $$
hence by applying $\frac{d}{dx}$ to both sides:
$$ n (1+x)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k} k x^{k-1} $$
$$ nx (1+x)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k} k x^{k} $$
By evaluating the last identity at $x=2$ we reach the same conclusion as before.

Comment: hey man! I inputed the problem wrong. There was only $k$ not $2^k$.

Comment: interesting way to think about this.

Comment: @NTT: you should avoid *chamaleon questions*, they invalidate answers. Luckily, in this case there is an easy fix: just ignore the part about red balls. In the *generating functions* part, evaluate at $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to find $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n k \binom n k.$

Let $X$ be the number of heads in in $n$ coin tosses. Then $\Pr(X=k) = \dbinom n k \left( \dfrac 1 2 \right)^n.$

But
$$
\operatorname{E}(X) = \text{average number of heads in $n$ tosses} \begin{cases}  =n/2 \\[10pt]
= \sum_{k=0}^n k \Pr(X=k) \end{cases}
$$

Hence those two expressions are equal.